# Edit a table cell

Tags: iphone

My table must provide several functions:

- clicking on a cell leades the user to a new view with more details (no problem)
- swiping over a cell delets the entry (also no porblem)
- tab & hold on a cell makes the text in the corresponding cell editable

How can I implement this feature? Ususally the text shouldn't be editable, only when the `UILongPressGestureRecognizer` function is activated. There shouldn't pop up a window or s.th. like that. There should just the cursor blink somewhere in the text of the cell and makes it possible to the user to add new / delete letters.

Thanks for your help

Comment: What have you done so far with this ? Do you get errors we could try to resolve ? The goal is to provide help resolving problems...

Answer (score 0):

Use a custom UITableViewCell.  Have both a label (the cell that normally displays the cell text), and a UITextField.  Make the UITextField hidden.  In the event of a long press, make the label hidden, and the text field not hidden.  Transfer the text information from label to text field and back again.  That should do it.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `UILabel` objects in your `UITableViewCell`, use `UITextField` objects.  By default set their `editable` property to `NO`.  This means they cannot pop up the keyboard.

However, in the event of a long press, set `editable` to `YES`, and call `[textField becomeFirstResponder]` on the desired text field.

Hope this helps you!